# Render object in form html tag in extjs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs3

I'm using extjs 3.4. I have a form. Inside I want to display some ajax content. But i'm getting [object object] whenever alert that variable. I tried `stringify` `Json.decode` But no luck. Here is my code,

```
var sourcePath = new Ext.data.Store({
                reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                    fields: ['path'],
                    root: 'rows'
                }),
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                    url: '/plugin/BODImageImport/admin/getsourcepath'
                }),
                autoLoad: true
            });
```

And my form,

```
var bodimportForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            html: "<p>Imgae source: <b>"+ sourcePath +"</b> folder in root directory</p>",
            url: '/plugin/BODImageImport/admin/import',
```

any help or hint would be very helpful for me.

**Update:**

My Json is looks like this,

```
{"rows":[{"path":"bodyshop\/tr\/media\/inbox"}]}
```

I just trying to get that path in html tag.

**Update:**
When i'm printing objects using console.log() I'm getting below things. But I don't know how to get my value,
[image: Console]

Answer (score 0):

Here sourcePath is a store instance.

So you cannot do html:

Imgae source: **"+ sourcePath +"**

In order to get the value inside the store you must do

```
//index you are interested
m = sourcePath.getAt( index ) //this will give the model m
//m.path to get the path
```

and inside your reader

```
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                    fields: ['path'],
                    root: 'rowsDir'
                }),
```

should have been

```
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                    fields: ['path'],
                    root: 'rows'
                }),
```

since your json root is rows and not rowsDir

Comment: Thanks Cyril. I tried  `m = sourcePath.getAt( index );
         alert(m.path);` but i got error in console  like 
`ReferenceError: index is not defined 
m = sourcePath.getAt( index );`

Comment: If you are interested in the first record in the list you need to pass index as 0
m = sourcePath.getAt( 0 )
Rather than doing alert i would recommend do console.log(m) and check the json in the browser console.

Comment: yeah, I tried that But I'm getting `TypeError: m is undefined`. In console log I'm getting `undefined`

Comment: do you get your path when you do console.log(sourcePath.data.items[0].data.path)